# Custom UITableViewCell in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I use Xamarin Studio to create a new custom table cell in a MonoTouch project (File -> New -> File... -> iOS -> iPhone Table View Cell). It creates MyViewCell subclass of UITableViewCell. The class already contains a static Create() method.

Then I use this class in table's GetCell method this way:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(MyViewCell.Key) as MyViewCell;

    if (cell == null)
    {   
        cell = MyViewCell.Create();
    }

    // my own code to update the cell content
    cell.Update(someData);

    return cell;
}
```

In Update method I use some subview transformations. The problem is that when the cell is first time created (Create method is called) the transformations are not applied.

But if I schedule the update to the next run loop iteration everything works fine:

```
NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.Zero, () =>
{
    cell.Update(someData);
});
```

What is the problem here? Can I solve the problem without using this hack?

Answer (score 0):

the first time a cell has not been added in the table, when you called Update

for cell subview transformation override PrepareForReuse method or LayoutSubviews method on the cell class, depending on what you need.

Comment: PrepareForReuse is not called on first usage, so it's not the case. LayoutSubviews seems the solution, but it doesn't work too - same result as if calling update right after creation.